# Boost::Hana tuple, best way to modify a value

Tags: c++, tuples, boost-hana

I'm pretty new to this powerful library. I was surprised I couldn't find an easy way to, given a tuple, return another tuple that just modifies a single element, by index.

Moreover, I want this method to be available also at **compile time**

E.g.:

```
auto tup = hana::make_tuple(1_c,2_c,3_c);
static_assert(modify(tup,1,2000_c) == hana::make_tuple(1_c,2000_c,3_c));
```

I think I can achieve this result by combining insert and remove_at, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear to others who might find "modify a value" to mean changing the run-time value, [`hana::at`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Iterable.html#ga8a484304380eae38f3d9663d98860129) and [`hana::at_c`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Iterable.html#ga4cb99cfbef936cb267e76f66f40f529c) as well as the corresponding `operator[]` can return mutable references to change the value at run-time. This does not change the type of the element:

```
hana::at_c<1>(tup) = 2000;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xErFNm

As far as replacing the element type and all, Boost.Hana does not support this directly, but looking at the implementation of `remove_at`, implementing a `replace_at` is straight forward:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <utility>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

template <typename Xs, typename X, std::size_t ...before, std::size_t ...after>
constexpr auto replace_at_helper(Xs&& xs, X&&x, std::index_sequence<before...>,
                                      std::index_sequence<after...>) {
  return hana::make_tuple(
      hana::at_c<before>(std::forward<Xs>(xs))...,
      std::forward<X>(x),
      hana::at_c<after + sizeof...(before) + 1>(std::forward<Xs>(xs))...);
}

template <std::size_t n>
constexpr auto replace_at_c = [](auto&& xs, auto&& x) {
    constexpr auto len = decltype(hana::length(xs))::value;
    return replace_at_helper(static_cast<decltype(xs)>(xs),
                             static_cast<decltype(x)>(x),
                             std::make_index_sequence<n>{},
                             std::make_index_sequence<len - n - 1>{});
};

auto tup = hana::make_tuple(1_c,2_c,3_c);
static_assert(replace_at_c<1>(tup,2000_c) == hana::make_tuple(1_c,2000_c,3_c));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/H2aySg

This is more efficient than composing other functions that would rely on creating intermediate tuples to shuffle values around.